# Fixing the footer to the bottom of the browser

Tags: css

Is there any way we can fix the footer to the bottom of the window even at the time of vertical scroll.  I have gone through some examples, but those never work with the vertical scroll.

Comment: Refer this http://limpid.nl/lab/css/fixed/footer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [sample](http://ryan.rawswift.com/2009/03/19/jstcky-a-stick-or-die-javascript-framework/) and its [google code base](http://code.google.com/p/jstcky/)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the bottom property to 0. Example:

```
.footer
{
    background-color:#FFFACD;
    bottom:0;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:250px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your css

```
html, body {height:100%;padding:0;margin:0;}
#footer {position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;width:100%;background-color:#f00;}
#scrollingbody {overflow:auto;height:100%;}
```

Here is your html

```
<div id="scrollingbody">content goes here</div>
<div id="footer">here is footer</div>
```

Comment: position: absolute; will not supported in IE 6 browsers

Comment: Your saying the CSS attribute position:absolute is not supported in IE6?  Having actually used it in IE 6, I can say for sure that it does because I just tested it!